# How to determine what page a PDF opens on?

Tags: pdf-generation, apache-fop

I'm generating multi-page PDF reports using [pentext](https://github.com/radicallyopensecurity/pentext), which uses Apache FOP. It all works fine, but when I open the resulting PDF (in macOS Preview), it always opens on the last page rather than the first. This makes me suspect there is some concept of "current page" that is saved as part of the document, which also means there should be some way of manipulating that so that reports open on the first page instead. Can anyone tell me how to set that using FOP?

Alternatively, is there some way of setting what page a PDF document opens on using some other tool that I can use to post-process it?

Comment: Opening a PDF does not modify the file itself; it's the _application_ (Preview, Reader, ...) used to open it that may remember the last visited page and re-open the file at the same position.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, however I've found this applies to PDFs created with FOP that have never been opened before. Essentially every doc I create with FOP *always* opens on its last page. Other PDFs do not do this (e.g. generated via print from LibreOffice), which is what makes me suspect FOP. I'm not suggesting that the reader modifies the PDF, but that the doc itself contains a setting for the page it opens on.

Comment: Is it possible that the generated PDFs have the same pathname of previously opened files, so that the application consider them the same (and opens them at the last position for the "old" file)?

Comment: Nope, unique pathnames for each one. I just checked something else: if I open a newly FOP-generated PDF file (which opens at the last page), scroll to the first page and select it in the sidebar, close the file, then reopen it, it still opens at the last page.